# Possibilities Of Dividing Cards

Tags: combinatorics

In a card game we give 13 cards for each of the 4 players.
How much division of card are there?

I thought it is ${4\choose1}*{52\choose 13}$, but the answer is $\frac{52!}{13!^4}$

where did I get wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be multinomal coefficient. We have 52 cards to seperate to 4 players, each of size 13. So:

$\dbinom{52}{13,13,13,13}$

Your way would be to count how many ways can you hand 13 cards out of 52 cards to one of four players, which is different than what the question asks for.

Answer (score 2):

We choose $13$ cards from $52$ and then $13$ from $39$ and finally  $13$ from $26$ so the number is
$${52\choose 13}\times{39\choose 13}\times{26\choose 13}$$

Comment: I see, but form where does the $13!^4$ come? I mean from which formula? (multi binomial?)